# Is it possible to send a condition as prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props, conditional-rendering

I've been wondering if there is a way to send a condition as a prop to a child component that needs some conditional rendering and its iterating a set of dynamic objects.

Let's say I want one of those objects to be conditionally rendered, so a do something like this:

```js
const Content = [{
  object: "One",
  value: one,
  name: "object1"
 }, {
  object: "Two",
  value: two, 
  name: "object2",
  condition: object1.value === "One" 
}]
```

So, depending on the value of the first object, who might be, let's say, a select tag, I want the second to be rendered.

Then we have our object:

Then, inside the component, I will be iterating the object and conditionally rendering inputs or selects.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This is the component

```
function FormCase ({ onSubmit, register, content }) {
    return (
        <Form id="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <Row className="form-row">
                {content.map((obj, idx) => {
                    return (
                        obj.conditional &&
                            <div className="form-group" key={idx}>
                                <label>{obj.name}</label>
                                <input className="form-control" value={obj.value} />
                            </div>  
                    )
                })}
            </Row>
            <Row className="submit-row">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </Row>
        </Form>        
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you mind giving more details with your code? This question is not so clear right now.

Comment: Would you mind adding the code also ?

Comment: I added some code there.

Comment: Looking at your code you already achieved the conditional rendering.
just change obj.conditional into obj.condition. If condition will be true, rendering will occur. By the way - never use index as key, use a unique value for each child.

Answer (score 0):

```
const content = [{
  object: "One",
  value: one,
  name: "object1"
 }, {
  object: "Two",
  value: two, 
  name: "object2",
  condition: value => value === "One" 
}]

// while rendering

const toRender = content.filter(item => !item.condition || item.condition("some value"));

// or filter function of your choice
```

then just render filtered items.

EDIT:

```
function FormCase ({ onSubmit, register, content }) {
    return (
        <Form id="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <Row className="form-row">
                {content.map((obj, idx) => {
                    if (idx > 0) { // don't check the condition for first
                      return (
                        obj.condition && obj.condition(content[idx-1].value) &&
                            <div className="form-group" key={idx}>
                                <label>{obj.name}</label>
                                <input className="form-control" value={obj.value} />
                            </div>  
                    )
                    } else {
                      return (
                           <div className="form-group" key={idx}>
                                <label>{obj.name}</label>
                                <input className="form-control" value={obj.value} />
                            </div>  
                    )
                  }
                })}
            </Row>
            <Row className="submit-row">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </Row>
        </Form>        
    )
}
```

So you just pass the function as a `condition` in your `content` array. During rendering you should check the `condition` with previous item value as parameter for your function.

You should adjust the logic - what to do when there is no `condition` function defined in your `content` object.

Comment: This is not very clear for me. Am I supposed to send the "toRender" variable as the condition?

Comment: I edited the answer using the code you added to the question